# C# MySQL Cannot extract data from one table and add to another table

Tags: c#, mysql, database

```cs
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionstr);
con.Open();    
string insertid = "SELECT UserID FROM login WHERE username =@U";
MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(insertid, con);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@U", username);
MySqlDataReader idread = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
idread.Read();
string id;
if (idread.HasRows==true)
{
    id = idread.GetString(0);
    string insertid2 = "INSERT INTO managementtest.fulldetails(UserID) VALUES(@I);";
    MySqlCommand cmd3 = new MySqlCommand(insertid2, con);
    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@I", id);
    MessageBox.Show("Detail Profile Created. User ID # " + id , "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

I have tried running this code. Everything runs fine but the value of id is not added into MySQL Database. I have checked the spelling of table name and all. It isn't working. string username is predefined and holds a specific value from a textbox.

Comment: and where do you rn the second code it should also be excuted

Comment: i am running the code in Visual Studio. I have tried running the same line as a query in MySQL Workbench and it works. I have tried debugging and it shows exactly what I want. all that is not happening is data being added to database

Comment: that is not what i mean you have a `cmd2.ExecuteReader();` but nothing for cmd3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot this

```
 cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
 cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
```